Does every cubic threefold contain a genus 5 curve of degree 8?
Since a genus $5$ curve $C$ of degree $8$ is a complete intersection of $3$ quadrics $Q_1,Q_2,Q_3$ in $\mathbb{P}^4$, I would guess that $C$ is contained in a cubic threefold $X = \mathbb{V}(f)$ when we can write $f = \sum_i L_iQ_i$ for linear terms $L_i$.
The space of such curves $M_5'$ is $36$-dimensional, whilst the space of cubic threefolds $U$ is $55$-dimensional. Note that I am counting the varieties together with their embedding in $\mathbb{P}^4$, not their isomorphism class.
The space of cubic threefolds containing $C$ is $14$-dimensional, by choosing $L_1,L_2,L_3$. This means that the universal family $Z \subset U \times M_5'$ is 50-dimensional, so by this dimension count I expect the answer to the question to be negative. Would anyone be able to characterize those cubic threefolds which have a curve of genus $5$ and degree $8$?
NOTE: By choosing a line $l\subset X$ and writing $l = P_1 \cap P_2 \cap P_3$ for generic hyperplanes $P_1,P_2,P_3$, we can write $f = \sum_i Q_iP_i$, and further one can show that $Q_1,Q_2,Q_3$ can always be chosen to be smooth. Is the intersection $\cap_i Q_i$ not expected to be complete then?

Isn't the space of cubic threefolds 34-dimemsional?

@WillSawin ah you are right! Dumb mistake on my part. So the space of genus $5$ curves of degree $8$ on a cubic threefold is $16$-dimensional? That would check out with some of my other calculations.

I didn't do the calculation you need to do to check that for a generic cubic threefold it's 16-dimensional instead of empty, but that's what I would expect, and it's less obvious whether there exist special cubic threefolds where the dimension is significantly higher.

By Theorem 10.1 of the following, every smooth cubic threefold has a 13-dimensional variety $N$ of connected, projective, nodal curves $C$ of genus 5 and degree 8 that are a union of a smooth curve $C′$ of genus 2 and degree 5 and a smooth plane cubic $C′′$ such that $C′\cap C′′$ is a set of 3 points. By deformation theory, the codimension of $N$ in the full moduli space $M$ of genus 5, degree 8 curves is at most 3. Since every irreducible component of $M$ has dimension at least 16, every irreducible component of $M$ that intersects $N$ has dimension 16: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0202067

@JasonStarr very nice paper! Do you reckon $J(X)$ is the mrc quotient of this component of $M$?

Possibly.  Ana-Maria Castravet is more expert on that these days, so she is a better person to ask.

This is just a follow-up to the question in the comment about rational connectedness of generic fibers of the Abel maps.  I believe they are rationally connected.  A general genus-5, degree-8 curve $C$ on $X$ is contained in (many) sextic K3 surfaces $S$ contained in $X$.  The curve moves in a $\mathbb{P}^5$-linear system on $S$.  That linear system should intersect $N$.  Then we can use residuation / liaison to reduce to the case of genus-$2$, degree-$5$ curves.

To construct a triple of quadrics $Q_1,Q_2,Q_3$ whose ideal contains $f$ one can use a trick. First, consider a line on $X$. It is given by three linear forms $L_1,L_2,L_3$, and the fact that it lies on $X$ means that there are three quadrics $Q_1,Q_2,Q_3$ such that
$$
f = \sum Q_iL_i.
$$
Therefore, these quadrics have the desired property.
This trick also shows that there are quite many triples $Q_1,Q_2,Q_3$ with this property, so it remains to check that among them there is a triple that defines a sufficiently nice curve.
Edit. Here is another way to produce a required curve from a line on $X$. Let $S \subset \mathbb{P}^4$ be a cubic scroll such that the line is a ruling of $S$. Then $X \cap S$ is a curve of degree $9$ containing the line as one of the components. The other component $C$ has degree 8, so it remains to show that its genus is 5.
Indeed, if $e$ and $f$ denote the class of the exceptional section and the ruling of $S$, then the class of $X \cap S$ is $3(e + 2f) = 3e + 6f$, hence the class of $C$ is $3e + 5f$. By the adjunction formula
$$
\deg(K_C) = 
(3e + 5f)(-2e - 3f + 3e + 5f) = 
(3e + 5f)(e + 2f) = 8,
$$
hence the genus of $C$ is 5.

It looks like there are $14$ dimensions coming from choosing $Q_1,Q_2,Q_3$ by exchanging terms between the $L_i$. There are $2$ more dimensions coming from choosing the line $l$ on $F(X)$. Does this cover all the cases? Also, I know how to choose $Q_1,Q_2,Q_3$ smooth, but how do I ensure that $\cap_i Q_i$ is smooth connected?
